# strsepf() - Parsing string using strsep with a scanf-like interface

Tags: c, strings, embedded

`vstrsepf` is string parsing utility function born from the idea of using `strsep` and `strtol` with a `sscanf`-like interface.

This is an attempt to build a safer `scanf` for embedded system application.

Some key design choices:

- Will destroy its input string (by adding '\0').
- No dynamic memory allocation.
- Reentry safe (RTOS and thread support)
- No string copy, only pointer address are changed.
- No floating point support.

Usage example 1:

```
// Parse IP string
char              test[] = "192.168.0.13";
char const* const format = "%3d.%3d.%3d.%3d";

uint32_t answer0 = 0;
uint32_t answer1 = 0;
uint32_t answer2 = 0;
uint32_t answer3 = 0;
int16_t  n = strsepf(test, format, &answer0, &answer1, &answer2, &answer3);

TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(192, answer0);
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(168, answer1);
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(0, answer2);
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(13, answer3);
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(4, n);
```

Usage example 2:

```
// Parse NMEA (GPS) message
char              test[] = "$GPBWC,081837,,,,,,T,,M,,N,*13";
char const* const format = "$%*sBWC,%d,%*s,%*s,%*s,%*s,%*s,%s,";

uint32_t answer0 = 0;
char*    answer1 = NULL;
int16_t  n = strsepf(test, format, &answer0, &answer1);

TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(81837, answer0);
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL_STRING("T", answer1);
TEST_ASSERT_EQUAL(2, n);
```

Try it online:
https://onlinegdb.com/BkTDY5EoS

---

`strtol_s.h` A safer implementation of strtol (needed for strsepf).

```
long
strtol_s(const char* buff, uint8_t base, int8_t* err)
{
    char* end;
    errno = 0;

    const long sl = strtol(buff, &end, base);
    if (end == buff) {
        *err = -1; //< not a decimal number

    } else if ('\0' != *end) {
        *err = -2; //< extra characters at end of input

    } else if ((LONG_MIN == sl || LONG_MAX == sl) && ERANGE == errno) {
        *err = -3; //< out of range of type long

    } else if (sl > INT_MAX) {
        *err = -4; //< greater than INT_MAX

    } else if (sl < INT_MIN) {
        *err = -5; //< less than INT_MIN

    } else {
        *err = 0; //< ok
    }
    return sl;
}
```

`vstrsepf.h` The string parser

```
/*
 * `vstrsepf` is string parsing utility function born from
 * the idea of using `strsep` with a `sscanf` interface.
 *
 * It is designed to be a safer `scanf` for embedded system application.
 *
 * Some key design  choices:
 * - Will destroy its input string (by adding '\0').
 * - No dynamic memory allocation
 * - No string copy, only pointer address are changed.
 * - No floating point support.
 *
 * ARGUMENTS:
 *  @param: mutStr - mutable input string.
 *  @param: fmt    - format string.
 *  @param: arg    - Aguments lists (va_list)
 *
 * FORMAT SPECIFIER:
 *
 * | Specifier   | Descriptions                                                    |
 * |-------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
 * | %i, %d, %u, | Any number of digits*                                           |
 * | %o          | Any number of octal digits (0-7)*                               |
 * | %x          | Any number of hexadecimal digits (0-9, a-f, A-F*                |
 * | %%          | A % followed by another % matches a single %.                   |
 * | %s          | A string with any character in it. A terminating null character |
 * |             | is automatically added at the end of the stored sequence.#      |
 *
 * FORMAT OPTIONAL SPECIFIER:
 *
 * | O Specifier | Descriptions                                                    |
 * |-------------|-----------------------------------------------------------------|
 * | *           | An optional starting asterisk indicates that the data is to be  |
 * |             | read from the stream but ignored.                               |
 * | width       | Specifies the maximum number of characters to be read in the    |
 * |             | current reading operation.                                      |
 *
 *
 */
int16_t
vstrsepf(char mutStr[], char const* fmt, va_list arg)
{
    if (mutStr == NULL || fmt == NULL) {
        return -1;
    }

#define SUPPORTED_SPECIFIER "dibouxs%"

    int count = 0;
    while (*mutStr && *fmt) {

        // printf("fmt = %c,  s=%c\n", *fmt, *mutStr);
        if (*fmt == '%') {
            fmt++;

            // A format specifier follows this prototype: [=%[*][width][modifiers]type=]
            char   specifierType = '\0';
            bool   noAssignFlag = false;
            size_t width = 0;
            for (; *fmt; fmt++) {
                if (strchr(SUPPORTED_SPECIFIER, *fmt)) {
                    specifierType = *fmt;
                    fmt++;
                    break; //< Specifier type is always the last element of a specifier string
                }

                if (*fmt == '*') {
                    noAssignFlag = true;

                } else if (*fmt >= '1' && *fmt <= '9') {
                    char const* tc;
                    for (tc = fmt; isdigit(*fmt); fmt++)
                        ;
                    width = strtol(tc, (char**)&fmt, 10);
                    fmt--;
                }
            }

            if (specifierType == '%') {
                mutStr++; //< `%%` is just the `%` character.
                continue;
            }

            char*      token;
            const bool continueUntilTheEnd = (*fmt == '\0');
            if (continueUntilTheEnd) {
                token = mutStr;
            } else {
                char termination[] = { *fmt, '\0' };
                token = strsep(&mutStr, termination);
                if (token == NULL) {
                    return -1; //< no token found
                }
                fmt++;
            }

            if (noAssignFlag) {
                continue; //< ignore it.
            }

            if (width > 0) {
                if (width < strlen(token)) {
                    return -1;
                }
            }

            int8_t strtolErr = 0;
            switch (specifierType) {
                /*********************************
                 * Scan string
                 *********************************/
                case 's': {
                    char** ptr = va_arg(arg, char**);
                    if (ptr == NULL) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    *ptr = token;
                    count++;
                } break;

                /*********************************
                 * Scan int
                 *********************************/
                case 'd':
                /* FALLTHROUGH */
                case 'i':
                /* FALLTHROUGH */
                case 'u': {
                    uint8_t   base = 10;
                    uint32_t* ptr = va_arg(arg, uint32_t*);
                    if (ptr == NULL) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    *ptr = strtol_s(token, base, &strtolErr);
                    if (strtolErr < 0) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    count++;
                } break;

                case 'x': {
                    uint8_t   base = 16;
                    uint32_t* ptr = va_arg(arg, uint32_t*);
                    if (ptr == NULL) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    *ptr = strtol_s(token, base, &strtolErr);
                    if (strtolErr < 0) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    count++;
                } break;

                case 'o': {
                    uint8_t   base = 8;
                    uint32_t* ptr = va_arg(arg, uint32_t*);
                    if (ptr == NULL) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    *ptr = strtol_s(token, base, &strtolErr);
                    if (strtolErr < 0) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    count++;
                } break;

                case 'b': {
                    uint8_t   base = 2;
                    uint32_t* ptr = va_arg(arg, uint32_t*);
                    if (ptr == NULL) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    *ptr = strtol_s(token, base, &strtolErr);
                    if (strtolErr < 0) {
                        return -1;
                    }
                    count++;
                } break;

                /*********************************
                 * We don't know.
                 *********************************/
                default: {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        } else { /* !(*fmt == '%') */
            if (*fmt != *mutStr) {
                return -1;
            } else {
                fmt++;
                mutStr++;
            }

        } // END if (*fmt == '%')

    } // END while (*mutStr && *fmt)
    return count;
}
```

`strsepf.h` An arguments wrapper

```
int16_t
strsepf(char mutStr[], char const* fmt, ...)
{
    int16_t rc;
    va_list arg;
    va_start(arg, fmt);
    rc = vstrsepf(mutStr, fmt, arg);
    va_end(arg);
    return rc;
}
```

---

While robustness and speed are my priorities, all suggestions are welcome.

Comment: I see that `strtol_s` returns a highly specific error message and `vstrsepf` just projects it to a binary and returns -1 on error. Could you think of a way of including that information?

Comment: Great point. 
To be honest, I mostly reused `strtol_s` from an old project. I could return better info about what failed with an enum.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to never design APIs revolving around variable arguments. The printf/scanf familes of functions are some of the buggiest, most dangerous functions - not just in in the history of C - but in the history of programming. It is not something you should look at for inspiration! Variable argument functions is a completely superfluous feature, originating from a time in the 1960-1970s where programming languages needed to brag about having lots of features, long before good programming practice was invented and established.

Comment: @Lundin 
While I do see the problem associated with variable arguments function, it seems like a valuable feature for building flexible API in c.

Do you have an alternative in mind ?

Comment: @gberth Pretty much all major C APIs out there use pointers to struct. And if needed, the structs can implement some manner of polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Small review

**Bug**

`case 'u': { ... *ptr = strtol_s(token, base, &strtolErr);` can form the wrong value as `strtol()` can limit values to 2<sup>31</sup>-1.  Same with `'x'`.  Better to use `strtoul()`.

**Type conflagration**

`long strtol_s()` looks like a function to convert a string to `long` yet it errors when out of `int` range and is curiously used in the code only for `uint32_t`.

I'd expect a `uin32_t strtou32_s()` or the like.  Maybe something like [`strto_subrange()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29378380/2410359)?

**Reduce error values**

In `strtol_s()`, as `(LONG_MIN == sl || LONG_MAX == sl) && ERANGE == errno` generates the same error value, I'd expect `sl > INT_MAX` and `sl < INT_MIN` to generate one same error value.

**Error checking omission?**

Interesting `width = strtol(tc, (char**)&fmt, 10);` lacks range checking.